# Edit Firebase Files Metadata From The Console

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

I know that Firebase metadata can be eddited programatically, as described here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/file-metadata

But for me it would be a lot easier to add some values directly from the Firebase console, but I can't seem to find any way to do that.

Comment: Sounds like a great feature request. But there's not a lot we can do about it here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since Firebase Storage is built on Google Cloud Storage, you can always go directly to the Google Cloud Storage console ([console.cloud.google.com/storage](http://console.cloud.google.com/storage)) and edit metadata on individual objects.

Comment: yaaaaaaaaaaaaaaayyyyyy !!!!! thx a lot :)